# Parsing NSData with Express.js and node-multiparty

Tags: ios, node.js, express, afnetworking

I'm building an iOS app that's hooked up to a Node/Express.js backend running MongoDB and using Nginx as a reverse proxy. On the client side, I'm using AFNetworking. I'm running into an issue when sending the password as an encrypted `NSData` object over the networking (I'm using [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor) with AES 256-bit encryption).
I have two authentication calls:

`/api/signup (POST)`

`/api/login  (POST)`

`signup` takes a multipart request and processes the form using [node-multiparty](https://github.com/andrewrk/node-multiparty/).

Here's my sample form parsing code:

```
var deferred = q.defer();
var form = new multiparty.Form();
var image, email, userName, password, path = null;

//attach the image, create the user, and embed a session token.
form.on('close', function(){
    console.log(password);

});

form.on('file', function(name, file){
    path = file.path;
});

form.on('field', function(name, value){
    if(name == "email"){
        email = value;
    }else if(name == "name"){
        userName = value;
    }else if(name == 'password') {
        password = value;
    }else return;
});

//user profile picture
form.on('part', function(part){
     if (!part.filename) return;
     if (part.name !== 'image') return part.resume();
     image = {};
     image.filename = part.filename;
     image.size = 0;
     part.on('data', function(buf){
       image.size += buf.length;
     });
});

// parse the form
form.parse(request);

return deferred.promise;
```

When the password is logged to the console, I get the expected output, mostly random acsii characters (G�Bgq���g��+ for example).

For the login call, it's NOT a multipart request, the password parameter just exists in `request.body.password`. When I log that property with the same password, I get something like this:

<03018858 90f432f1 3230fc6d 3b419e06 a7d1b382 dab31581 4f622184 9d412ba2 1a7ddbda c416e203 57fee0e0 bf553ddf ace1e8c7 af098c5e f5c37b59 68ceb8c4 36dbf12e 3a9d3d15 fdbe5aee bb19bc94 2a8d>

It looks like the password parameter in multipart requests is getting parsed as the string value while the password parameter in the normal post request is what would be logged to the Xcode console for an `NSData` object.

Now I just can't figure out where this is happening, if it's on the client side with AFNetworking (maybe it handles `NSData` parameters different for multipart) or if it's a result of node-multiparty. Even then, I'm not sure how to mitigate the issue, apart from unnecessarily changing the regular `POST` call to be a multipart request so I can get the same behavior. Any help or insight would be appreciated.

EDIT: I feel like I should mention that passwords in my app are first encrypted using `RNCryptor` then sent to the backend and encrypted again with [bcrypt](https://github.com/ncb000gt/node.bcrypt.js/). The problem I'm running into is when the same password entered on the client side, they don't match on the server despite being run through the same encryption process.

Comment: `bcrypt` is a Key Derivation Function, not encryption. Think of is as a fancy hash function.

Comment: `bcrypt` is a Key Derivation Function, not encryption, it can not be reversed. Think of it as a fancy hash function.